# How to get all plugin dependencies from Gradle?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-dependencies

I'm trying to make a Gradle plugin that will list all dependencies used to build the project. For simple compile and buildscript dependencies, that's fairly easy:

```
val dependencies = project.allprojects.asSequence().flatMap { project ->
    (project.buildscript.configurations + project.configurations).asSequence()
        .filter { it.isCanBeResolved }
        .flatMap {
            val resolved = it.resolvedConfiguration
            resolved.rethrowFailure()
            resolved.firstLevelModuleDependencies.flatMap { dep -> dep.allModuleArtifacts }
        }
}
```

(then use `it.id.componentIdentifier as ModuleComponentIdentifier` to get to group, module and version, and `it.type` and `it.classifier` for those properties)

However, this misses jars used only by plugins. For example, when I apply the Kotlin plugin:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
}
```

the list will not include everything. Specifically, it'll include `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin` and some siblings, but it doesn't include the pom dependency on `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin` which is needed as well.

Can I get those dependencies out of the Gradle model as well?

Comment: Did you [take a look at this plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin), that does version checking and could contain something useful? Perhaps there's a hidden "technique" you can piggyback from there.

Comment: Good idea @MartinMarconcini. I took a look at the code, but it looks like the plugin only handles direct dependencies, not transitive ones. Which makes sense, since those are the only ones that need updating.